# Interpolation function evaluation and timing

Tags: function-construction, interpolation, timing

Lets define two identical functions $f$ and $g$ in a slightly different way

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -5, 5}]];
g = Function[x, Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -5, 5}]][x]];
Timing[Do[g[1], {i, 1000}]]/Timing[Do[f[1], {i, 1000}]]
{12.0023, 1}
```

Does the second definition calculates the interpolating function every time $g$ is evaluated?

Comment: I see now it is because of the `HoldAll` attribute of the function. A workaround: `g = Function[x, 
  Evaluate@Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -5, 5}]][x]]`

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You have passed the same function `f` into a pure function so it is evaluated every time you calculate `g`. Specially you define `f` by `=` so Mathematica calculates it once and then re-use it in `Do` loop. For the sake of demonstration if I define f by `:=`:

```
f1 := Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -5, 5}]];
f2 = Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -5, 5}]];
Timing[Do[f1[1], {i, 1000}]]/Timing[Do[f2[1], {i, 1000}]]
```

The result is

```
 {11.91, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see , but this is not a `SetDelayed` issue, I think it is more related to the `HoldAll` attribute of Function, now I realize.

Comment: You are right. As the Documentation says: "Function has attribute HoldAll. The function body is evaluated only after the formal parameters have been replaced by arguments."